# What is the BRST-anti-BRST formalism?

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, physics, gauge-theory

What is the BRST-anti-BRST formalism?
Is the Sp(2) doublet the ghost, antighost pair?
Introductory accounts of this subject seem to be hard to find. I would appreciate a reference for someone who knows BRST well.

Answer (score 5):

Jim. I think the following references might be helpful:

- Grégoire, Philippe; Henneaux, Marc. Hamiltonian BRST--anti-BRST theory. *Communications in Mathematical Physics* **157** (1993), no. 2, 279--303. http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104253940.
- P Gregoire and M Henneaux, Antifield-antibracket formulation of the anti-BRST transformation, 1993 *J. Phys. A: Math. Gen.* **26** 6073 http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/26/21/045

The idea seems to be to choose a non-minimal (with extra ghosts and anti-fields) solution of the usual BRST (or BV-BRST) master equation with extra structure (invariance with respect to an anti-BRST transformation, which is another cohomological vector field/differential). As far as I can tell, the main difference/advantage seems to be in how the gauge fixing is done. In the usual formalism, one adds a BRST-exact term to the Hamiltonian (or action), which is the image of a *gauge fixing fermion* under the BRST transformation. In this non-minimal formalism, the gauge fixing fermion is itself chosen to be anti-BRST exact, which means that it is the image of a *gauge fixing boson* under the anti-BRST transformation.

I'm afraid that I'm not familiar enough with the applications of this formalism to judge why this way of gauge fixing is actually advantageous. I also can't comment intelligently about the $sp(2)$ structure.

Comment: Thanks especially for the precise references - see also my next comment

Answer (score 3):

To complete Igor Khavkine's answer: as explained [here,](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807053) in the Sp(2) covariant description the BRST and anti-BRST charges form a doublet with opposite ghost number.

Comment: I was aware of those words ` the BRST and anti-BRST charges form a doublet' but had missed where anyone mentioned the ghost numbers - would an example be ghost,antighost in the BV case? will study the refs